# Heating element to be powered by a solar panel, a battery or a dynamo

Tags: power-supply, power

For an art project, a heating element is to be powered by a solar panel, a battery or a dynamo using a switch to choose the power source.

Could the negative poles of the three sources be directly connected to the heating element with only the positive poles being switched?

Comment: You can even mix DC power sources (solar&chemical cells) and AC ones (dynamo) that way, if the latter is harder to switch electronically.

Answer (score 0):

Without further info and thinking how you can just use 3 different batteries as 3 different sources, yes you can connect the negatives together and only switch the positive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the source negatives may be directly connected while the positives are switched using a single-pole three-way selector switch.

[image]